# javascript: returning value from anonymous function

Tags: javascript, callback, anonymous

How can I get the value of `var result` in this code?

I know this is a basic problem but I'm looking for the solution since 3 days. Can you give me any suggestion please?

```
function foo(myCallback){
}

function bar() {
    var result = foo(function(){
        var result = "hello"; 
        return result;
    });
}

var showResult = bar();
alert(showResult);
```

Comment: You can get it in the `callback`

Comment: `function foo(myCallback) {
}
function bar(cb) {
  foo(function() {
    var result = "hello";
    cb(result);
  });
}
bar(function(res) {
  alert(res);
});`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call the callback and return the value of it and inside your `bar` function, you need to return the result as well

```js
function foo(myCallback){
    // return the value of the call myCallback()
    return myCallback();
}

function bar(){
    var result = foo(function(){
        var result = "hello"; 
        return result;
    });
    // return the result
    return result;
}
var showResult = bar();
alert(showResult);
```

A bit simplified it could be

```js
function foo(myCallback){
    return myCallback();
}

function bar(){
    return foo(function(){
        return "hello"; 
    });
}
var showResult = bar();
alert(showResult);
```

Comment: You could even simply replace the initial `var result` declaration with `return` itself. Actually, in this case, all `var result = ...; return result;` could be replaced with `return ...`

Comment: Thank you very much Nina Scholz this is the good answer ! :-) It is good to see your first answer which is the same  as my question. And then I can see a simplified version. Thank you !

Comment: @Nina Scholz I'm sorry but the system tells me I haven't enough reputation to be able to vote for your answer ...

Comment: @zm455 You should be able to vote on your own question, and you can most certainly mark an answer to your own question as correct :)

Comment: Hello @somethingThere stackoverflow's system tells me I can't vote for my own post. I would be more than happy to be able to vote for people who helped me. I just need 2 people votes for my question and I will be 15 reputation which is the score I need to be able to accept answer and vote

Comment: @zm455 really? You can't mark your own question as answered? Hmmm... I find that weird. Why let people ask questions if you won't let them mark the right answer regardless of reputation? Anyhow, gave your question an upvote, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the vote(if you are the one who voted). Just tell me where do I have to click to be able to accept an answer or just make my auqestion as "answered" ? I'm looking for that button since yesterday.

Comment: Please have a look here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the return statements. It isn't clear what you want to return.

It works like this:

```
function foo(myCallback){
  return myCallback();
}

function bar(){
    var result = foo(function(){
        var result = "hello"; 
        return result;
    });
  return result;
}
var showResult = bar();
alert(showResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are stuck using callbacks, but fortunately you can pass parameters in your callback functions:

```
// define your functions
function foo(myCallback){
    myCallback();
}

function bar(callback){
    var result = foo(function(){
        var result = "hello"; 
        callback(result);
    });
}

// now run it
bar(function(showResult){
    alert(showResult);
});
```